# Array задачу не могу решить, вывожу четные элементы, а нечетные не выводятся

Tags: c++, массивы

Дан массив A размера N. Вывести вначале его элементы с нечетными номерами в порядке возрастания номеров, а затем — элементы с четными номерами в порядке убывания номеров.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    int a[10]; 
    int n, i; 
    cout<<"n:"; 
    cin>>n; 
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i) cin>>a[i]; 
    { 
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) cout<<a[i*2+1]<<" "<<"\t"; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: как то так. п.с. я только учусь 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int n, i;
    cout<<"n:";
    cin>>n;

    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
 cin>>a[i];
    {
    
 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout<<a[i*2+1]<<"  "<<"\t";
 }       

    return 0;
}

Comment: У вас только один цикл вывода, он и выводит ровно то, что вы попросили. Добавьте такой же цикл для вывода нечетных

Comment: @Mike я просто убрл, так как он вообще не показывал, + если ввести 10 элементов в четных 5, то остальные 5 он выводит рандомно

Comment: @entithat Ну, кашу маслом не испортишь, компилятор не обращает внимания на лишние начала блоков (если они сбалансированы).

Comment: @Mike, что-то новенькое для меня :)

Comment: @AdilShamuratov Так добавьте обратно. Надо что бы он хоть что то выводил, а потом смотреть почему именно он выводит не то. И кстати, вы специально такое форматирование кода делаете, что бы казалось, что второй цикл выполняется внутри первого, хотя это абсолютно не так и фигурные скобки не имеют смысла.

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое, за совет, я только начал учится. Затянуло, но вот некоторые задачи выводят ошибку, вот и интересно как их исправить. Спасибо больое!)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Нечетные
for (i=1; i<n; i+=2) 
    cout<<a[i]<<" "<<"\t"; 
cout << endl;
// Четные
for (i= ((n-1)/2)*2; i>= 0; i-=2) 
    cout<<a[i]<<" "<<"\t";
```

Примерно так...

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы было в обратном порядке четные?

Comment: А в каком порядке выводятся у меня? Нечетные - в прямом, четные - в обратном...

Comment: странно, но у меня четные в прямом, не четные в обратном.

Comment: Ну убедитесь сами - https://ideone.com/hxc2Iw Нострадамлю :), что вы уверены, что самый первый элемент массива имеет индекс 1...